# FatalErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and Caffeinated Modules and when I try to go somewhere I get this error.

> FatalErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 42: 
>   Modules\Users\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::Modules\Users\Providers{closure}(): Failed opening required 'Modules/Users/Http/routes.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

This is my routes.php in my Users module

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function()
{
    Route::get('admin/', [
        'uses' => 'UsersController@admin',
        'as' => 'login'
    ]);
});
```

I'm not sure what other code I need to give to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it.
I just replace '\' in my path with '/'.